# How can I calculate the total impedance of a second-order low-pass filter?

Tags: filter, impedance, low-pass

How can I calculate total impedance of this low-pass filter? Also, how can I measure the phase difference?

[image]

For example:
L = 12.73 mH
C = 198 μF
R = 8 Ω
F = 100 Hz

[image]

Simulators show a graph as top:
Impedance @ 100 Hz ~= 5.9 Ω.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the impedance of your circuit is given by:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}&=\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\left(\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\space\text{||}\space\text{R}\right)\\
\\
&=\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\frac{\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\cdot\text{R}}{\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}+\text{R}}\\
\\
&=\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\frac{\text{j}\omega\text{C}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\cdot\text{R}}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}+\text{j}\omega\text{C}\cdot\text{R}}\\
\\
&=\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\frac{\text{R}}{1+\text{j}\omega\text{CR}}\\
\\
&=\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\frac{\text{R}}{1+\text{j}\omega\text{CR}}\cdot\frac{1-\text{j}\omega\text{CR}}{1-\text{j}\omega\text{CR}}\\
\\
&=\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\frac{\text{R}\left(1-\text{j}\omega\text{CR}\right)}{1+\left(\omega\text{CR}\right)^2}\\
\\
&=\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\frac{\text{R}-\text{j}\omega\text{CR}^2}{1+\left(\omega\text{CR}\right)^2}\\
\\
&=\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\frac{\text{R}}{1+\left(\omega\text{CR}\right)^2}-\frac{\text{j}\omega\text{CR}^2}{1+\left(\omega\text{CR}\right)^2}\\
\\
&=\frac{\text{R}}{1+\left(\omega\text{CR}\right)^2}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}+-\frac{\text{j}\omega\text{CR}^2}{1+\left(\omega\text{CR}\right)^2}\\
\\
&=\frac{\text{R}}{1+\left(\omega\text{CR}\right)^2}+\left(\omega\text{L}-\frac{\omega\text{CR}^2}{1+\left(\omega\text{CR}\right)^2}\right)\cdot\text{j}\\
\\
&=\underbrace{\frac{\text{R}}{1+\left(\omega\text{CR}\right)^2}}_{:=\space\Re\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)}+\underbrace{\omega\left(\text{L}-\frac{\text{CR}^2}{1+\left(\omega\text{CR}\right)^2}\right)}_{:=\space\Im\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)}\cdot\text{j}
\end{split}\tag1
\end{equation}

Where \$\alpha\space\text{||}\space\beta:=\frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha+\beta}\$.

So, we can see that the modulus of the impedance is given by:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left|\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right|&=\sqrt{\Re^2\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)+\Im^2\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)}\\
\\
&=\sqrt{\left(\frac{\text{R}}{1+\left(\omega\text{CR}\right)^2}\right)^2+\left(\omega\left(\text{L}-\frac{\text{CR}^2}{1+\left(\omega\text{CR}\right)^2}\right)\right)^2}
\end{split}\tag2
\end{equation}

And the argument of the impedance is given by:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\arg\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)&=\arg\left(\Re\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)+\Im\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)\cdot\text{j}\right)\\
\\
&=\arg\left(\frac{\text{R}}{1+\left(\omega\text{CR}\right)^2}+\omega\left(\text{L}-\frac{\text{CR}^2}{1+\left(\omega\text{CR}\right)^2}\right)\cdot\text{j}\right)\\
\\
&=\begin{cases}
0&\text{if}\space\Re\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)>0\space\wedge\space\Im\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)=0\\
\\
\arctan\left(\frac{\Im\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)}{\Re\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)}\right)&\text{if}\space\Re\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)>0\space\wedge\space\Im\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)>0\\
\\
\frac{3\pi}{2}+\arctan\left(\frac{\Re\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)}{\left|\Im\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)\right|}\right)&\text{if}\space\Re\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)>0\space\wedge\space\Im\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)<0
\end{cases}\\
\\
&=\begin{cases}
0&\text{if}\space\omega=0\space\wedge\space\omega=\frac{1}{\text{CR}}\sqrt{\frac{\text{CR}^2}{\text{L}}-1}\\
\\
\arctan\left(\frac{\omega}{\text{R}}\cdot\left(\text{L}+\text{CR}^2\left(\text{CL}\omega^2-1\right)\right)\right)&\text{if}\space\omega>\frac{1}{\text{CR}}\sqrt{\frac{\text{CR}^2}{\text{L}}-1}\\
\\
\frac{3\pi}{2}+\arctan\left(\frac{\text{R}}{\omega\left(\text{CR}^2\left(1-\text{CL}\omega^2\right)-\text{L}\right)}\right)&\text{if}\space0<\omega<\frac{1}{\text{CR}}\sqrt{\frac{\text{CR}^2}{\text{L}}-1}
\end{cases}
\end{split}\tag3
\end{equation}

---

So, for the given values we get:

- Total impedance:
  \begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
  \underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}&=\frac{3125000}{390625+39204 \pi ^2}+\pi  \left(\frac{1273}{500}-\frac{990000}{390625+39204 \pi ^2}\right)\cdot\text{j}\\
  \\
  &\approx4.01902+3.99854\text{j}
  \end{split}\tag4
  \end{equation}
- The modulus:
  $$\left|\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right|=\frac{1}{500} \sqrt{1620529 \pi ^2+\frac{10000000 \left(625000-126027 \pi ^2\right)}{390625+39204 \pi ^2}}\approx5.66929\space\Omega\tag5$$
- For the argument, we can see that \$\Re\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)>0\$ and \$\Im\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)>0\$, so we need to use the second case in the piecewise function, \$(3)\$, and find:
  $$\arg\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)=\arctan\left(\frac{\pi  \left(2265625+49906692 \pi ^2\right)}{1562500000}\right)\approx0.782844\space\text{rad}\tag6$$

Comment: Thank you for useful answer. Upvote is for me. Regarding impedance, your formula is correct and I used it. But your answer regarding the phase difference was not consistent with the simulator. Of course, this was before you edited your answer and I haven't checked the changed formula yet.

Comment: Please don't delete your answer. It shows step by step and very useful for me and other rookies.

Comment: @POPI Both are correct, I am sure.

Answer (score 9):

I have looked at this quickly, applying the fast analytical techniques or FACTs as described in my [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119236371) on the subject. You first start by determining the input resistance for \$s=0\$: open the cap and short the inductor, you "see" \$R_0=R_L\$. Then you turn the excitation off (it would be a current source for an impedance determination) and you calculate the various time constants in this mode.

For the numerator, you short the current source (the *nulled* response across the current source makes it a short circuit for the zero determination) and you determine the new time constants in this mode. The below picture shows the step in which you determine all the results by inspection only, no equations:

[image]

Then assemble the results, test versus the brute-force expression and there you go:

[image]

You can now extract the magnitude and phase from these expressions and use them to plot your graphs in Excel if you wish:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

> *How can I calculate total impedance of this low-pass filter?*

$$Z_{IN} = j\omega L + \dfrac{\frac{1}{j\omega C}\cdot R_L}{\frac{1}{j\omega C}+R_L}$$

> *Also how can I measure the phase difference?*

You can use a two-channel oscilloscope and estimate the phase angle based on the time delay between input and output. Of course, you need to drive the input with a sinewave.

> *For example : L = 12.73 mH C = 198 uF R = 8 Ohm F = 100 Hz*

At 100 Hz, the phase angle will be very close to 90° lagging at the output: -

[image]

Image from [my basic website](http://www.stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RLC%20LPF.html#RLC_low_pass_filter_type_2).

Comment: Add your calculations to your question please.

Comment: Sorry, numerator= 1, denominator = 8.12 and final result = 8.12 ohms

Comment: Your spreadsheet calculation doesn't seem to apply complex operators into the formula and solution.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: @POPI the impedance of 5.657 ohms looks about right.

Comment: Yes and thanks alot. In the simulator, ESR was considered for the capacitor and inductor, which I did not include. And this was a mistake on my part. I'm a newbie :).